# Going from two hdd to one hdd cannot boot

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, boot

I've had two HDD both with Vista installed on them. This is because the old Hitachi HDD failed previous and I added a Seagate HDD and just loaded Vista onto one of its two partitions. Normally when I booted up it give me an option to choose which one to boot from, which I'd choose the Seagate but the Hitachi did work Again if I wanted it to boot from it. Now the Hitachi has died and I've managed to recover all the data from it. I've now removed it completely from the PC. But now when I turn on it says I have the option to enter BIOS etc and then it says Boot from CD/DVD: Disk boot failure, insert system disk and press enter.  Why is it simply not booting from the Seagate automatically? I don't want to reinstall Vista. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The broken harddrive must have had the **Master Boot Record (MBR)**, now that it is no longer there, the computer does not know which operation systems are installed, and how to start them.

You will get errors like:

```
Error loading operating system

Missing operating system

Invalid partition table
```

It is however easy to fix.

First, start your computer with your windows cd/dvd.

Make sure you have the correct boot device selected in your bios:

[image]

In the Vista install click "Repair your computer"

[image]

Choose the operating system to repair and click Next. When the System Recovery Options dialog comes up, choose the Command Prompt:

[image]

Now type **bootrec.exe** and press Enter. This will rebuild the boot configuration data and hopefully fix your problem. You can also run the command with switches to fix just the master boot record (/fixmbr), the boot sector (/fixboot), or rebuild the entire BCD (/rebuildbcd).

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go. When connecting the broken HDD back in, Vista does boot up from the newer drive but takes a long time, much more than before. Can anything be done while at this position. Can I run the commands from this point instead?

Comment: I think the only way is to use the CD. More info since you can still boot into old vista: http://www.maximumpc.com/article/ask_doctor/moving_mbr

Comment: Thanks, it took some doing, but it looks like I've got there in the end as it's all booting fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Might be bad MBR ..
Boot with your Vista CD .. And you choose "Repair installation" (or something like that) ..